# For Next Loop not working in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to automate the pull of data from multiple pages of a website into a workbook.  On one sheet titled `Events` I have 3 columns, the third of which (column C) is where I want the data pulled from, in the format `URL;http://frc-events.usfirst.org/2015/txsa/rankings`.  I attempted to use the following code to go down my 108 rows, fetching all data:

```
Sub GetData()
    For x = 1 To x = 108
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Events").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Events").Activate
        mystr = Cells(x, 3)
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Cells(x, 2)
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            mystr, Destination:=Range( _
            "$A$1"))
            .Name = "rankings"
            .FieldNames = False
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, upon running it, nothing happens.  I've attempted to isolate it, and by setting x to any single number, it will work and create a single sheet.  When attempting the run the loop however, as I said, I don't get a result.  Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

**BONUS question:**
I'm sure this wouldn't likely be *too* difficult, but if instead of creating individual sheets for each new import, I wanted the data from all web pages to go into the same sheet, how might I go about that?  (All data will be in the same format, (that is to say, same number of columns, though the amount of rows differs from page to page.

Comment: @DanDonoghue got the the first question.  The answer to the bonus question lies in the page source for the website you linked:  "PLEASE DO NOT SCRAPE WEBPAGES FOR EVENT DATA!
      We now have an API that allows easy access to event and team
      data. It is easier for developers, and helps keep this server
      available for the public who are seeking basic event information.
      For more info, visit our project website at:
      [https://usfirst.collab.net/sf/projects/first_community_developers/](https://usfirst.collab.net/sf/projects/first_community_developers/)"

Comment: Nice catch :), I didn't even think of looking at the actual data / source coming in.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
For x = 1 To x = 108
```

to this:

```
For x = 1 To 108
```

Comment: I caught that too.  I actually had to try it to see what it did - shockingly it compiles, but just immediately exits the loop.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why it compiles, I know why it doesn't work as x is empty and the statement actually says For X = 1 to nothing because of this but I don't know why it allows you to do it. I did the test myself also and also like you was somewhat shocked :)

Comment: Ahhh... I just realized why it compiles.  It actually evaluates as `For x = 1 to False`.  Add the imaginary parentheses: `For x = 1 to (x = 108)`

Comment: Oh right that makes sense :). I never would have worked that out, I can't think of a time when it would make sense to try and do this??

Comment: It's a stretch, but you could use it to conditionally skip the last iteration if you're looping backwards: `x = 10: For x = x To x = 9 Step -1: Debug.Print x: Next`. Wow, that makes me feel dirty...